# How add a jpeg file to gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I am working on Gazebo 4 and I want to add a 2D environment consisting of roads, lanes etc.I have made a jpeg file which include all this, how can I add that file in gazebo as world.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7114/how-add-a-jpeg-file-to-gazebo/) by [Rahul Sharma](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/924/rahul-sharma/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just had a similar need - a carpet on the floor. What worked for me was the following (with Gazebo 1.9):

1. In the world file:

   12.88 12.88 0.005
            
          
          
            
              file:///full/path/to/materials.material
              Materials/Carpet
            
          
        
      
      1
2. materials.material file:

   material Materials/Carpet
   {
   technique
   {
   pass
   {
   ambient 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   diffuse 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   specular 0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0 12.5

   ```
      texture_unit
      {
        texture carpet14x14.jpg
        filtering trilinear
      }
    }
   ```

   }
   }

I pulled this one from somewhere else and just replaced the script name and texture filename.

3. carpet14x14.jpg in the same folder as materials.material

---

Originally posted by [glinde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/526/glinde/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2